# Video 'Snipping' Android - Possible?

Tags: android

Hey guys, I'm looking into creating an application that requires a video file taken on the mobile phone, open it and allow the user to cut the video using two sliders, one for IN(the beginning) and the other for out(end of the clip you want), this will then create a new file and my app will use it then.

Does this sound feasible? Where should I start looking in order to do this quite simple concept? Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android SDK has no video-editing (not even cropping) capabilities. So you'd need to write your own.

To do this you'd need to know 3gpp video/audio file format and also a way to decode the file (for showing in the UI).

This is by no means a trivial task.

Comment: With my [mp4parser](http://mp4parser.googlecode.com) it is at least possible to cut the video at its I-frames. Have a look at the ShortenExample.